# How to hide css grid row gap

Tags: css, css-grid

I am using css grid in my project.I have 4 rows,4 columns and grid-gap 10px. For first and second row will take 100% width. But sometimes i need to hide second row based on server response.If i do like display none for second row there is gap 20px between 1st row and 3rd row. I want to hide row with gap in css grid otherwise it looks odd there.

code:

if i add hideRow display,height properties grid gap between first and third row 20px. I wanted to make it 10px.

```
   .content > * {
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
}

.Header{
   grid-area: Header;
}
.hideRow{
    /*display: none;*/
    /*height: 0;*/
    grid-area: hideRow;
}
.first{
    grid-area: first;
}
.second{
    grid-area: second;
}
.third{
    grid-area: third;
}
.fourth{
    grid-area: fourth;
}
.fifth{
    grid-area: fifth;
}
    
            <div style={{padding:'5%'}}>
                <div className={"content"}>
                    <div className={"Header"}>
                        Header
                    </div>
                    <div className={"hideRow"}>
                        hiderow
                    </div>
                    <div className={"first"}>
                        first
                    </div>
                    <div className={"second"}>
                        second
                    </div>
                    <div className={"third"}>
                        third
                    </div>
                    <div className={"fourth"}>
                        fourth
                    </div>
                    <div className={"fifth"}>
                        fifth
                    </div>
    
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Could we get some code so we can understand easier?

Comment: without any code, hard to help, example where the gap remains 10px  when you display to none one row: `body {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
div {/* there is 4 of them */
  border: solid;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}`

Comment: @lime can you check i added code

Comment: @skyshine How are you using the HTML?

Comment: @skyshine Adding the HTML with this would be very helpful. We can then turn it into a snippet so we can execute it an see what issues it is producing.

Comment: @lime i updated code can you check it

Comment: When you hide (display: none) an area, you have to change grid-template in its parent: this will remove gap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to create a class that override your `grid-template-areas`:

```
.content {
   grid-template-areas: "Header Header Header Header"
                        "hideRow hideRow hideRow hideRow"
                        "first second fifth fifth"
                        "third fourth fifth fifth";
}
```

with:

```
.content-hide-row {   
    grid-template-areas: "Header Header Header Header"
                        /* deleting this row*/
                        "first second fifth fifth"
                        "third fourth fifth fifth";
}
```

And adding it to the content container when you need to hide the row.

Also adding a class with `visibility: hidden` and `display: none` like this:

```
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
```

and then attaching it to the hideRow when you need it.

I leave here a snippet and tell me if this could help.

```css
.content {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 60px 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
  
    grid-template-areas: "Header Header Header Header"
                        "hideRow hideRow hideRow hideRow"
                        "first second fifth fifth"
                        "third fourth fifth fifth";

}

.content-hide-row {
  grid-template-areas: "Header Header Header Header"
                       
                        "first second fifth fifth"
                        "third fourth fifth fifth";
}

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.content > * {
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    
}

.header{
   grid-area: Header
}

.hideRow{
   grid-area: hideRow;
}

.first {
  grid-area: first; 
}

.second{
  grid-area: second;
}

.third{
  grid-area: third;
}

.fourth{
  grid-area: fourth;
}

.fifth{
    grid-area: fifth;
 }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="hideRow">hideRow</div>
  <div class="first">First</div>
  <div class="second">Second</div>
  <div class="third">Third</div>
  <div class="fourth">Fourth</div>
  <div class="fifth">Fifth</div>
</div>

<div class="content content-hide-row">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="hideRow hide">hideRow</div>
  <div class="first">First</div>
  <div class="second">Second</div>
  <div class="third">Third</div>
  <div class="fourth">Fourth</div>
  <div class="fifth">Fifth</div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you saying create two template areas based on requirement disabling one template area ?

Comment: exactly, and in theory you should not have any problems in your project

Comment: for removing gap between two rows to make different grids how much it is feasble

Comment: Or, if you want, you can change the grid-template when you are on small/mobile screen you can add a media query, like `@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) { .content {grid-template-areas: /* new template here*/} }` and ofcourse `display: none;` for that row inside the media query.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet:

```css
.content > * {
    background: green;
    padding: 10px;
}

.Header{
   grid-area: Header;
}
.hideRow{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    grid-area: hideRow;
}
.first{
    grid-area: first;
}
.second{
    grid-area: second;
}
.third{
    grid-area: third;
}
.fourth{
    grid-area: fourth;
}
.fifth{
    grid-area: fifth;
}  
.mainDivPadding{
    padding: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDivPadding" cstyle={{padding:'5%'}}>
  <div class="content" className={"content"}>
    <div class="Header" className={"Header"}>
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="hideRow" className={"hideRow"}>
      hiderow
    </div>
    <div class="first" className={"first"}>
      first
    </div>
    <div class="second" className={"second"}>
      second
    </div>
    <div class="third" className={"third"}>
      third
    </div>
    <div class="fourth" className={"fourth"}>
      fourth
    </div>
    <div class="fifth" className={"fifth"}>
      fifth
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I had some issues with your `className={"hideRow"}` recognizing the `visibility: hidden;` and `position: absolute;` I've added in the `hideRow` class to the tag you're looking to be hidden. However, this should work.

Comment: I added your changes(position,visibility) in my css code.Still same 20px gap between first row and third row

Comment: @skyshine do you have any other styles effecting it? I've added classes to the other `div` tags to see the CSS being applied and I'm not having issues with this snippet. Maybe try copying and pasting it in now.

Comment: I copied your code but margin between first row and third row still 20px gap, if you want i can attach screenshot

Comment: @skyshine I'm not too sure how much the screenshot would help because _in theory_ we should be running the same code, but post it anyway. Maybe it will show that one of us is doing something different.